# MIPS pipeline load use hazard with branch

Tags: mips, branch, pipeline, cpu-hazard

Today I'm studying in the MIPS pipeline and finding out one interesting thing.
Seeing the code below:

```
I1: lw  $s1, 0($s3)
I2: add $s4, $s5, $zero
I3: beq $s1, $s5, 8
```

In order to reduce penalty of branch, we make compare two register data in ID stage.
Making me confuse is that whether this condition is a kind of load use hazard or not? Does it cause a stall in pipeline?

I'm wondering whether there is a forwarding form MEM stage to ID stage to avoid pipeline stall in this case?

Because the textbook seems not mention it and I don't know how the exact MIPS works, I guess it won't cause a stall.

Thanks eveyone!!!